# How to position 2 radio columns side by side

Tags: php, html, css, radio-button, css-float

I'm having problems getting my radio buttons side by side. They won't go side by side. When they do go side by side it messes up my checkbox below this code.

I've tried floating it differently, using padding and margin, I've tried adjusting the height and the width

```
<div class="style" style="width 100px; float:left; height 100px; margin:0px;">
<!-- this code asks the suer what clothing style they like. They have a lot of options. The code is like the gender code -->
Select a style: <br /> 
<label> <input type="radio" name="style" value="Casual" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['style'] == 'Casual') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Casual</label><br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="style" value="Athletic" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['style'] == 'Athletic') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Athletic</label><br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="style" value="Vintage" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['style'] == 'Vintage') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Vintage</label><br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="style" value="Formal" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['style'] == 'Formal') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Formal</label><br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="style" value="Streetwear" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['style'] == 'Streetwear') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Streetwear</label><br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="style" value="Rocker" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['style'] == 'Rocker') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Rocker</label>
</div>

<br />

<?php
if(($_POST['size'] == NULL) && ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')){
    echo "<strong>Please select a clothing size!</strong><br />";
}
?>

<div class="size" style="width 100px; float:left; height 100px; margin:0px;">
Select a size: <br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="size" value="Extra Small" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['size'] == 'Extra Small') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Extra Small</label><br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="size" value="Small" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['size'] == 'Small') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Small</label><br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="style" value="Medium" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['size'] == 'Medium') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Medium</label><br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="size" value="Large" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['size'] == 'Large') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Large</label><br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="size" value="Extra Large" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['size'] == 'Extra Large') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Extra Large</label><br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="size" value="2X Large" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['size'] == '2X Large') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>2X Large</label>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />




<?php
if(($_POST['conf'] == NULL) && ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')){
    echo "<strong>Please confrim your style and size!</strong><br />";
}
?>

<!-- this checkbox makes the sure the user is satisfied with their selection. They have to select it manually, but it is sticky so if they check it and forget another field it will remain checked -->
Check to confirm your style and size <input type="checkbox" name="conf" value="conf"
<?php
if ($_POST['conf'] == 'conf') {
    echo "checked";
}
?>
/>
```

This is what the code looks like now:[mycode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7PTM.png)

I would like them to be side by side with no interference with the checkbox below this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to delete the `<br />` tag in line 53, try now :

```
<div class="style" style="width 100px; float:left; height 100px; margin:0px;">
<!-- this code asks the suer what clothing style they like. They have a lot of options. The code is like the gender code -->
Select a style: <br /> 
<label> <input type="radio" name="style" value="Casual" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['style'] == 'Casual') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Casual</label><br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="style" value="Athletic" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['style'] == 'Athletic') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Athletic</label><br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="style" value="Vintage" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['style'] == 'Vintage') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Vintage</label><br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="style" value="Formal" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['style'] == 'Formal') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Formal</label><br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="style" value="Streetwear" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['style'] == 'Streetwear') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Streetwear</label><br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="style" value="Rocker" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['style'] == 'Rocker') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Rocker</label>
</div>

<?php
if(($_POST['size'] == NULL) && ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')){
    echo "<strong>Please select a clothing size!</strong><br />";
}
?>

<div class="size" style="width 100px; float:left; height 100px; margin:0px;">
Select a size: <br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="size" value="Extra Small" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['size'] == 'Extra Small') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Extra Small</label><br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="size" value="Small" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['size'] == 'Small') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Small</label><br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="style" value="Medium" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['size'] == 'Medium') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Medium</label><br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="size" value="Large" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['size'] == 'Large') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Large</label><br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="size" value="Extra Large" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['size'] == 'Extra Large') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Extra Large</label><br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="size" value="2X Large" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['size'] == '2X Large') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>2X Large</label>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />




<?php
if(($_POST['conf'] == NULL) && ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')){
    echo "<strong>Please confrim your style and size!</strong><br />";
}
?>

<!-- this checkbox makes the sure the user is satisfied with their selection. They have to select it manually, but it is sticky so if they check it and forget another field it will remain checked -->
Check to confirm your style and size <input type="checkbox" name="conf" value="conf"
<?php
if ($_POST['conf'] == 'conf') {
    echo "checked";
}
?>
/>
```